# How to copy data to k8s persistent volume?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, persistent-volumes

I'm working on **k8s** airflow setup and I need a flow to update DAGs with ho hassle.
Looks like the most "kubernetish" way is to use persistent volume.
But how to write data (DAG python files) from outside the cluster into persistent volume?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use external volume provider or setup NFS to achieve this. Volume has to be able to mount on different machines and then you need to reference it to Kubernetes with `ReadWriteMany` `persistentVolume` type.

Comment: Could you please provide some code or other details?

Comment: Sadly persistent volumes are environment specific, you should search it whatever your environment. Then you should be able to know how to do it specifically and if ReadWriteMany is supported in that provider.